# Finding line beginning using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

#### Finding Line Beginning using Regular expression in Notepad++

I want to strip a 4000-line HTML file from all the jQuery "done" attributes in a div.

```
<DIV class=menu done27="1" done26="0"
done9="1" done8="0" done7="1"
done6="0" done4="20">
```

should be replaced with:

```
<DIV class=menu>
```

In [this experiment](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#experiment) I can do it with this regular expression:

```
[ ^]done[0-9]+="[0-9]+"
```

Using Notepad++ 5.6.8 Unicode, with a file encoded in ANSI, I'm putting this regex in the "Find what" field. It only replaces the 5 occurrences starting with a space, it will miss the 2 occurrences starting at the beginning of a line.

How can I construct a regex to remove all the attributes of an HTML element starting with a keyword?

Comment: Every programming related question is valid on stackoverflow. Nobody will blame you for not knowing something or call you a newbie. The worst questions are te questions not asked

Comment: Maybe you should rename you question to reflect that you have trouble with regex pattern matching multi-line expressions

Comment: Using `^` worked for me

Answer (score 14):

**Extended Replace "\n" with "LINEBREAK "**

Thanks a lot to all for these timely replies. Following your advices, here's what I did:

- *"Notepad++ > View > Show Symbol > Show End Of Line"* shows "CR+LF" at each line end.
- *"Notepad++ > Search > Find", "Search mode" = "Normal"*, made sure that "Find what" = "LINEBREAK" finds nothing
- *"Search mode" = "Extended", "Find what" = "\n\r"* only finds the double-breaks (CR + LF + a blank line); "\n  \r" find nothing; yet "\n" does find exactly all line breaks, and only them.
- **Saving** my "Towncar.htm" test file as "**Towncar_02.htm**" (also encoded in ANSI)
- Under "Extended", replaced all "\n" with "LINEBREAK " **(notice the trailing space)**
- Under "Regular expression", replaced each occurrence of:

  ```
   done[0-9]*="[0-9]*"
  ```

(**Be careful to check there is THE HEADING SPACE before "done"**
  **and there is NO TRAILING SPACE!** see below)

with an empty string

- Under "Extended", replaced each occurrence of "LINEBREAK" with "\n" (*no trailing space* this time after "LINEBREAK"!)
- Checked that the resulting "Towncar.htm" file (after a few cosmetic reformatting) looked OK and pretty, and that after refresh, it still rendered the same as the "Towncar_02.htm" backup.

**Recalls and Notes:**

- This forum apparently works well in Chrome 4; but with some browsers (e.g. IE6 and other discontinued ones), under some circumstances, it causes some artifacts; so, be careful:
- even if the forum doesn't show it in your browser, there ***is*** a heading space, i.e. at the *beginning* of the Regex (the " done..." Regular expression above) and *inside* it, so to replace *only* strings starting with " done", with the starting space, thus making even surer to NOT alter eventual other strings with "undone" or "methadone" or else
- same way, even if the forum shows one in your browser, there is ***no trailing space*** at the end of the Regex!
- in the Regex, [0-9] matches 1 and only 1 occurrence of any decimal digit (characters in the 0-9 range); IOW it matches « 0 » or « 1 » or « 9 » etc, but NOT « 01 » or « 835 » or « » (the empty string) or whichever.
- * (asterisk) matches 0 or more times the previous character (here it matches the empty string or any string made exclusively of digits)
- samewise, + (plus sign) matches 1 or more times the previous character (here it matches any string, at least 1 character long, made exclusively of digits)
  Ref: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Notepad.2B.2B_regex_syntax

Comment: Wow!, this is very well-written and detailed answer, Impressive! I've voted on both question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like Notepad++ too but the regexing is really a pain. If you insist on using Notepad++ try this:

- First find out which newline
  characters are being used in your
  document (View>Show Symbol>Show End
  Of Line)
- Delete those line-breaks by replacing
  them with a single space (Search and replace. CR is \r LF is \n. Be sure to tick "Extended" search mode)
- Regex-replace `done[0-9][0-9]*=\"[0-9][0-9]*\"`
  with the empty string (be sure to put
  a single space before the regex
  expression)

Voila! Not very nice n clean but it works ;o)

After that if you want it human-readable again you could use the HTMLTidy functions

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it! Unfortunately, the complete solution in Notepad++ would have to be a 3 step process.

1. Regex search/replace with the following search: `\<done[0-9]+="[0-9]+"[ ]*` Of course, leave the replace field empty, so that it will simply delete everything that matches. (In Notepad++ understanding of regular expressions `\<` represents the "beginning of a word".)
2. Select the portion of text affected by your previous search/replace. You don't want to select the entirety of your document, because we're going to...
3. Strip newlines. Hit Ctrl-F to bring up the Search/Replace dialog again and this time select "Extended" search mode, instead of "Regular expression". Depending on the format of your document you are going to want to search for either `\n` or `\r\n`. The replacement field should, again, be empty. Also, make sure that the "In Selection" checkbox is checked.

Click "Replace All" and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is:

1. Goto "Search" and "Replace"
2. Input "\n" in "Find what"
3. Input your string in "Replace with"
4. Select "Extended" in "Search Mode"
5. Click "Replace All"

It will plug your string at the beginning of each line except the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, Notepad++ Regex cannot do that

Notepad++ using Scintilla regex engine, its per line based, so multiline search / replace cannot be done.

> Note that \r and \n are never matched
>   because in Scintilla, regular
>   expression searches are made line per
>   line (stripped of end-of-line chars).

Quoted from http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html