# Multiline regex in VS2015 or NP++

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, notepad++

I need to replace the following pattern across multiple files.

`this\.dialogs = {.*};`

This works fine when I set the `single line` flag here: 
https://regex101.com/r/dF2yG3/2

However I can't get this to work in an editor like VS or Notepad++, it will only match a single line.
How do I change the regex or set flags in any of these editors so I can make it span multiple lines?

Comment: *`.` matches newline* in Notepad++.

Comment: Does `this\.dialogs = {(.|\n)*};` work?

Comment: @StevenDoggart: This is a very bad construct. Very inefficient.

Comment: Well, actually, that's not even right.  It probably ought to be `this\.dialogs = {[^}]*};`

Comment: Unless the `{}` must be balanced.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I know, though if he's doing it in an editor, it's likely a one-time operation, so the split-second difference in performance will be irrelevant.  And yes, if he wants them balanced, that a whole other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note you would only want to use

```
(?s)this\.dialogs = \{.*\};
```

if you want to match a string from `this.dialogs = {` up to the *last* `}`.

To only match up to the closest `};`, use

```
(?s)this\.dialogs = \{.*?\};
```

The `(?s)` inline modifier forces a dot to match any character *inlcuding* a newline.

[image]

**In Notepad++**, you can use ***`.` matches newline in Notepad++*** option in the *Find and Replace* dialog instead of `(?s)`.

[image]

**In Visual Studio 2015** (and in VS2012, VS2013, too), you need to use

```
this\.dialogs = {[\s\S\r]*?};
```

to match a string from `this.dialogs = {` up to the closest `};`

[image]

Comment: Now, I think that is enough. If you need to match balanced `{}`, you will need to use `this\.dialogs = (\{(?>[^{}]|(?1))*\});` expression in Notepad++. VS find and replace does not support balanced constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the brackets and activate `. matches newline` In notepad:

`this\.dialogs = \{.*\};`

[image]

Or better use
`this\.dialogs = \{[^}]*\};`