# OR Without Capture Regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to use an OR operator in Notepad++ but not capture the match that's found. Is that possible? From my experimentation, you need to put OR expressions inside brackets, meaning Notepad++ captures them.

## Example Use Case

Just one of many possible use cases would be, we might want to use an OR operator to match any character, including newlines, but don't want to globally turn on "matches newline". We want to be able to do this without capturing groups all the time. This is discussed here: [Regex not matching text with newlines in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791240/regex-not-matching-text-with-newlines-in-notepad/60191976#60191976).

Comment: To make a group non-capturing, use `(?:[pattern])` instead of `([pattern])`. In this case, `(?:a|b)`

Comment: Oh seriously? It's that simple??? Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys. I had seen that on some answers and mistook it for lookahead. That works. Cheers.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Posted as answer so we can get this question closed out :)

Comment: Why not match `[ab]+` and replace with a space? The group before and after is optional and will be in the replacement.

Comment: The fourth bird... Yes I realised that after... actually my use case is a little different. It's for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791240/regex-not-matching-text-with-newlines-in-notepad/60191976#60191976

Comment: Note that because all parts are optional `([^ab]*)(?:[ab]*)([^ab]*)` will also turn an empty string in a space.

Comment: yeah you're right... a poor example to be fair. I've replaced it with a link to that other question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a group non-capturing, use

```
(?:[pattern])
```

instead of

```
([pattern])
```

In this case:

```
(?:a|b)
```

Answer (score 0):

To match any character including newline using Notepad++:

1. Check `. matches newline`
2. Use `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]` or `[\w\W]`
3. Prefix the regex (or only a part of it) with `(?s)` and stop with `(?-s)`

Comment: Toto appreciate it but that's not the question I'm asking here...

Comment: @ColmBhandal: You said in the question: “Suppose we want to use an OR operator to match any character, including newlines,” my post answers the question.

Comment: That was just an example use case. It's a good answer to the example use case, but that was just demonstrating one instance where you might want this. Perhaps your answer would be better suited to the question that inspired that example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791240/regex-not-matching-text-with-newlines-in-notepad/60191976#60191976