# Replace regex for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

[image]

Tried using regular expression feature in notepad++. But since i am not used to it cant find any solution. I have huge file and dont wanna do it manually. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287404/using-regular-expressions-to-do-mass-replace-in-notepad-and-vim. But i cant convert that logic to solve my problem

Comment: I tried that for you, when i checked the option"wrap around", it works, expression inserted in "find" replaced by "replace"

Comment: can you paste that for me ?

Comment: so you want simply to remove "< /item>< item>" from any "< /item>< item>Text< /item>< item>" ?

Comment: yes only remove "< /item>< item>" after text

Comment: @Shabbir [edit] your question. The picture does not match your question text, that's why you are getting questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a group, specify them by "()" then use it again by "\n", if there more than one group, use them as they appear in the regex: \1, \2 ... and so on

[image: regex in notepad++]

Comment: you are welcome friend, plz select the answer as accepted, so others can benifit.